# Side lengths are equal but visually look unequal

Tags: java, division

I have the following code, and as you can see I divide the same value by 3 each time I do `pencil.forward();` yet when I the sides look unequal. Code:

```
import gpdraw.*;

public class buildShape {
public SketchPad paper = new SketchPad(500,500);
public DrawingTool pencil = new DrawingTool(paper);

public void drawKochCurve(int level, double initialSize){
    if (level < 1){
        pencil.forward(initialSize);
    } else {
        drawKochCurve(level - 1, initialSize);
        pencil.forward(initialSize / 3);
        pencil.turnLeft(60);
        pencil.forward(initialSize / 3);
        pencil.turnRight(120);
        pencil.forward(initialSize / 3);
        pencil.turnLeft(60);
        pencil.forward(initialSize / 3);
    }
  }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    buildShape myKoch = new buildShape();
    myKoch.drawKochCurve(1,90);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @kjhughes why don't the side look equal if when I debug it shows they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursion is inadequate. You need to recursively call draw curve for each segment, else it will not create a fractal curve.

Change it to:

```
} else {
    drawKochCurve(level - 1, initialSize / 3);
    // pencil.forward(initialSize / 3);
    pencil.turnLeft(60);
    drawKochCurve(level - 1, initialSize / 3);
    // pencil.forward(initialSize / 3);
    pencil.turnRight(120);
    drawKochCurve(level - 1, initialSize / 3);
    // pencil.forward(initialSize / 3);
    pencil.turnLeft(60);
    drawKochCurve(level - 1, initialSize / 3);
    // pencil.forward(initialSize / 3);
}
```

Comment: wow, this makes it visually equal! why though? isn't it the same thing?

Comment: @user2895567: does it look to be the same thing? This is the basic recursive formula for creating a Koch snowflake curve.